# Access variable from another class in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two classes `OpenInvitation` and `Acceptinvitation` I want to access `self.socketIOReqAccept`, which is a socketIO object from `OpenInvitation` to `Acceptinvitation`

**OpenInvitation** class

```
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import threading

class OpenInvitation():
    def __init__(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.socket)
        thread.start()

    def socket(self):.
        def getSID(args):
            NOWsocketID = args
            self.socketIDfromOpenforPlay = NOWsocketID
            print(NOWsocketID)

        self.socketIOReqAccept = SocketIO('http://192.168.219.1', 5200, LoggingNamespace)
        self.socketIOReqAccept.on('s_id', getSID)
        self.socketIOReqAccept.wait()
```

I am trying to accsss `self.socketIOReqAccept` variable from open Invitation class.

I have tried `socketIO = self.OpenForPlay.socketIOReqAccept` in the another thread but it is stopping GUI which I am running simultaneously.

Please Help me out with this.

Comment: I don't see a `Acceptinvitation` object in your `OpenInvitation` class.

Comment: I want to access `self.socketIOReqAccept` in another class from `openinvitation` class which is a socket client object

Comment: `OpenInvitation` don't have a `socketIOReqAccept` attribute.

Comment: it is inside the ` def socket(self):`

Comment: @ArjunBorkhatariya  That is `socketIDfromOpenforPlay`, not `socketIOReqAccept`.

Comment: @ArjunBorkhatariya I do not see how `socketIO = self.OpenForPlay.socketIOReqAccept` could possibly stop your GUI for a significant time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `self.sockerIOReqAccept` within the init method:

```
from socketIO_client_nexus import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import threading

class OpenInvitation():
    def __init__(self):
        self.socketIOReqAccept = SocketIO('http://192.168.219.1', 5200, LoggingNamespace)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.socket)
        thread.start()

    def socket(self):.
        def getSID(args):
            NOWsocketID = args
            self.socketIDfromOpenforPlay = NOWsocketID
            print(NOWsocketID)

        self.socketIOReqAccept.on('s_id', getSID)
        self.socketIOReqAccept.wait()

oi = OpenInvitation()
socker = oi.socketIOReqAccept
```